# Stored procedure returning the result of an UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table that is used to store an incrementing numeric ID (of type INT). It contains a single row. The ID is incremented using a query:

```
UPDATE TOP(1) MyTable
WITH(TABLOCKX)
SET NextID = NextID + 1
```

I would like to move this into a stored procedure that returns the value that was in the NextID column *before* it was incremented, but am unsure how to do this using OUTPUT parameters. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guest you cannot use [identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28SQL.80%29.aspx) type.

Comment: @Grzegorz  Not an option in this case. Sometimes I need to set the value to an arbitrary number - either in software of manually in sql management studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for SQL Server 2005+, try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Get_New_My_Table_ID
    @current_id INT = NULL OUTPUT    -- Declared OUTPUT parameter
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE TOP(1) MyTable WITH(TABLOCKX)
    SET NextID = NextID + 1
    OUTPUT DELETED.NextID

COMMIT TRANSACTION

RETURN 0
GO
```

the results of `OUTPUT` don't need to go into an actual table, it can be a result set.

test it out:

```
declare @MyTable table (NextID int)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (1234)


SELECT 'BEFORE',* FROM @MyTable

PRINT '------------<<<<UPDATE>>>>---------'
UPDATE TOP(1) @MyTable
    SET NextID = NextID + 1
    OUTPUT DELETED.NextID
PRINT '------------<<<<UPDATE>>>>---------'

SELECT 'AFTER',* FROM @MyTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
       NextID
------ -----------
BEFORE 1234

(1 row(s) affected)

------------<<<<UPDATE>>>>---------
NextID
-----------
1234

(1 row(s) affected)

------------<<<<UPDATE>>>>---------
      NextID
----- -----------
AFTER 1235

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks KM. That works for me. Since the query is simpler (and presumably more efficient) than Tom's, I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL2005 or later the previous values for updated values can be retrieved using the OUTPUT clause.

Given that only one value will be returned I don't know how this compares with Tom's approach. I suspect that Tom's will be faster as there is an extra read but no overhead of creating a table variable. (**Edit:** and of course mine still has to read the table variable as well!)

```
CREATE PROC blah
@OldId int OUTPUT
AS

DECLARE @OldIds table( NextID int);


UPDATE TOP(1) MyTable
WITH(TABLOCKX)
SET NextID = NextID + 1
OUTPUT DELETED.NextID INTO @OldIds

SELECT @OldId = NextID
FROM @OldIds
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. +1 for that. I decided to accept Tom's solution because it avoids the need for a temporary table. Seemed slightly simpler.

Comment: @Andy - Yep I agree. It's a shame that `@OldId =  DELETED.NextID` doesn't appear to work.

Comment: The `OUTPUT` clause is the way to go, but you ruined it by using the temp table. `OUTPUT` doesn't need to go into a table, it can be a result set, see my answer.

Comment: @KM Was working off the requirement that it go into an OUTPUT parameter but I see that wasn't such a requirement in the end :-)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add in some error checking, etc. I also assumed that the table is a one-row table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Get_New_My_Table_ID
    @current_id INT = NULL OUTPUT    -- Declared OUTPUT parameter
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    SELECT
        @current_id = COALESCE(next_id, 0)
    FROM
        dbo.My_Table WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

    UPDATE dbo.My_Table
    SET next_id = @current_id + 1

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

To use the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @my_id INT

EXEC dbo.Get_New_My_Table_ID @current_id = @my_id OUTPUT
```

Comment: @Tom he wants the *before increment* value returned.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that works for me. The idea of using an initial select before the update had occurred to me, but I wrongly thought that HOLDLOCK couldn't be used with TABLOCKX, so I couldn't see a way to keep the lock. Looks like it can. Also you've introduced me to the COALESCE statement, which I wasn't aware of!

Comment: @Martin  True, but I can easily adapt his solution.

Comment: Edited to return the current value

Comment: far more complicated than it needs to be, you can do this in a single UPDATE statement, see my answer.

Comment: @KM I've accepted your answer, but to me (as a someone who isn't a sql expert) Tom's answer was easier for me to understand.